# How to change column width in DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have created data grid view like this:

[image]

I want to change the column width. What should I do?
Should I change the code in designer.cs or just in .cs?

Update:

```
private void sqlConnStaff()
    {
        BindingSource dbBindSource = new BindingSource();

        SqlCommand com;
        com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);

        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.CommandText = "view_staff";

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        IDCabang = new SqlParameter();
        IDCabang.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
        IDCabang.Size = 5;
        IDCabang.ParameterName = "@IDCabang";
        IDCabang.Value = IDCabangC;
        IDCabang.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        com.Parameters.Add(IDCabang);

        con.Open();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        dbBindSource.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
        // you can make it grid readonly.
        dataGridView3.ReadOnly = true;
        // finally bind the data to the grid
        dataGridView3.DataSource = dbBindSource;

        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Width property on the grid column like:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;
```

Or you can set the Width of the column in designer, modifying `desinger.cs` is generally not recommended, instead go the Design View there modify the column width property.

If you are binding the resultset from code and creating the column as well from the (code based on the resultset) then you have to specify / modify the width in the code. If you are designing the grid in design view and adding column from there then define the width in Design view. Go to DataGrid properties, Columns -> Add new Column there modify the width:

[image]

Comment: Where should I set the width property in .cs? Because it only contains lots of event click functions.

Comment: @NgFajarChandra, just do that after setting the `DataSource`.

Comment: no, it didn't. I fetch the data from the database SQL not making the column by myself. So the width of the column is resized by itself as the program fetches it from the database.

Comment: @NgFajarChandra, no specifying it in the code after setting the DataSource, you have **do that in code**.

Comment: @NgFajarChandra, in the second last line, after  `dataGridView3.DataSource = dbBindSource;` place `dataGridView3.Columns[0].Width = 200;`

Comment: @NgFajarChandra, try removing the line `dataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);`

Comment: should I change anything on the properties of the datagridview?

Comment: @NgFajarChandra, that is really strange, Could you try the same thing in a separate small project with just one form and a grid, because it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`DataGridViewColumn.Width`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx) property.

> Gets or sets the current width of the column.

```
DataGridViewColumn firstcolumn = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
column.Width = 150;
```

You can set your `.Width` property as a pixel, default value is `100`.

You can change it if you want to use in Design View as Habib *[pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16540548/447156)*.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in designer: click on `DataGridView` then on this small arrow in upper right corner of gird and go `Edit Columns -> Select Column -> Width` default is 100.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cant see the image. Is blocked by my work firewall but if you want to change the width i would advise never to modify the designer.cs

The designer.cs is auto generated code and people just assume this is not modified so it could become a pain in the ass to fix at a later date if needed.

Modify it in the .cs files.